# Horizontal legend with title on top in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to put the title of the legend on top, whereas the values are distributed horizontally but I cannot. Any hints will be very appreciated.

The code below provides the graph below, but I don't have space on my graph so I need something like this:

Sex

Female Male

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  sex = factor(c("Female","Female","Male","Male")),
  time = factor(c("Lunch","Dinner","Lunch","Dinner"), levels=c("Lunch","Dinner")),
  total_bill = c(13.53, 16.81, 16.24, 17.42))

 lp1 <- ggplot(data=df1, 
          aes(x=time, y=total_bill, group=sex, shape=sex, colour=sex)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
   legend.direction = "horizontal",
   ) +     
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#0000CC", "#CC0000"),
                     name = 'Gender') 
    lp1
```

[image]

Comment: You do know that you don't really need to double up on the encoding of gender to both colour and shape.  Simply using colour would do quite well, and simplify your legend a great deal.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
cols <- c("#0000CC", "#CC0000")

df1 %>%
  ggplot(aes(time, total_bill, group = sex, shape = sex, colour = sex)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_shape(
    guide = guide_legend(
      direction = "horizontal",
      title.position = "top"
    )
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = cols,
    name = "Gender",
    guide = guide_legend(
      direction = "horizontal",
      title.position = "top"
    )
  )
```

[image]

Comment: For those who want to have the same effect for continuous scales: use [`guide_colourbar`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/guide_colourbar.html)